# Как запустить чужой проект в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

Все классы подсветились оранжевым и написано что нет SDK. SDK подключил 1.8(пользуюсь им в другом проекте уже очень долго), а в этом проекте классы после подключения все равно остались оранжевыми(J) и проект не запускается. Когда захожу в Run -> Edit cofigurations -> Application и выбираю Main class среди своих файлов, то не горит кнопка ОК. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо нажать правой кнопкой на папке с классами, и выбрать "Mark Directory As ..." -> "Source Root"

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало!